# Replace HTML Tag with another HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace some HTML Tag with another HTML Tag with php or jquery .

My Current Tag (Default) :

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home</a></li>
```

I want to replace above HTML tag with

```
<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle active"> Home</a></li>
```

---

Example :

Default tag : `<h1> tag </h2>`

Replaced tag : `<h2> tag </h2>`

I already search many articles on stackoverflow but didnt founded solution for it.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Just saw your question again. You just need to add:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active");
```

---

> **Example:**
>
> Default tag: `<h1> tag </h2>`
>   Replaced tag: `<h2> tag </h2>`

You can use `.replaceWith()`:

```js
$("h1").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<h2 />", {
    html: $(this).html()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> tag </h1>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply praveen, So your saying to make like this `$("<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home</a></li>").replaceWith("<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle active"> Home</a></li>")`

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma Check again...

Comment: Like this `$("<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home</a></li>").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home1</a></li>", {
    html: $(this).html()
  });
});`

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma Man, I have updated again. See the update. Refresh the answer.

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma You just need `$(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active");`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a class `active` on `a`, for that just do

```
$('<li class="dropdown"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home</a></li>').find("a").addClass("active")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have created a custom function where you can pass the class to be added along with the target element and it would output the entire html back.

```
$.fn.AddNewClass = function(newClass,targetElement)
{
   $(this).contents().filter(function()
   {
      if($(this).is(targetElement)){
          var clone =  $(this);          
          $(clone).addClass(newClass);
          $(this).replaceWith($(clone));
       }
   });  

    return $(this)[0].outerHTML;
}

var ele = "<li class='dropdown'><a href='index.html' class='dropdown-toggle'>Home</a></li>";
var newEle = $(ele).AddNewClass('active','a.dropdown-toggle');
alert(newEle);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/so000t49/5/